# Is there a non-activex approach to scanning documents into a web app?

Tags: image-scanner

I am working on a web application that is a pretty simple and straightforward application except for on thing: it needs to be able to get documents from the scanner. I don't want to force the user to scan documents manually, save them, and then browse to them to upload the file, and I would like to avoid Active-X if possible (though feel free to make recommendations that include active-x). Is there a good way to do this through a web app? Can silverlight access scanners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with Silverlight 4.

```
<Button x:Name="btnAquireImage" Content="Aquire Image from Scanner/Camera" Click="btnAquireImage_Click" />


private void btnAquireImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   using (dynamic CommonDialog = ComAutomationFactory.CreateObject("WIA.CommonDialog"))
   {
       dynamic imageFile = CommonDialog.ShowAcquireImage();
       if (imageFile != null)
       {
           //insert file upload code
       }
   }
}
```

Source: http://www.brianlagunas.com/index.php/2010/02/19/silverlight-4-accessing-system-devices-with-com-interop/

Comment: I appreciate this answer. It may be what I end up doing, but I'm hoping to find a way that doesn't require the user to run out of browser. (I'm not hopeful that I will find a way, however)

Comment: Honestly, I don't think you will find anything that will work other than custom plugins that will only work with certain browsers.  At least with Silverlight, you have cross browser compatibility.