# Code alternatives for document imaging in C# (Not OCR)

Tags: c#, image, pdf, document

I have been asked to design a web based document imaging solution in C#. So far I have found only expensive SDK modules like Accusoft's `ImagXpress` and the like. `MODI` looked promising but seems more OCR centric which might be above and beyond the scope.

Is there a solution in .Net that would allow me to code in the document scanning, manipulation / viewing with the PDF format without buying expensive SDK's? I am hoping for a point in the right direction to research.

Simple Scope:

- Scan document to PDF format
- View/save document

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You could use Silverlight to acquire a raster image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155998/is-there-a-non-activex-approach-to-scanning-documents-into-a-web-app), then use a PDF generation library either in [Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523715/how-to-create-pdf-on-silverlight-4) or Asp.net (server-side) to generate the PDF.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It turned me on to some great ideas.